# Postgres set local "special case"

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I was glancing through the `SET` documentation and am not 100% sure I grok the special case of `SET` followed by `SET LOCAL` (I'm about to go glance through the code).

> The effects of SET LOCAL last only till the end of the current
> transaction, whether committed or not. A special case is SET followed
> by SET LOCAL within a single transaction: the SET LOCAL value will be
> seen until the end of the transaction, but afterwards (if the
> transaction is committed) the SET value will take effect.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html

Answer (score 1):

I tracked it down, I was missing the implicit concept that `SET` means `SET SESSION`, e.g.

```
begin;

-- this persists post transaction, assuming commit
set session statement_timeout to '10s';

-- this lives for the life of the transaction
set local statement_timeout to '10s'; 

-- do other awesome things

commit;
```

It made a bit more sense reading the GUC variable values

> ### Saving/Restoring GUC Variable Values
>
> Prior values of configuration variables must be remembered in order to
> deal with several special cases: RESET (a/k/a SET TO DEFAULT),
> rollback of SET on transaction abort, rollback of SET LOCAL at
> transaction end (either commit or abort), and save/restore around a
> function that has a SET option. RESET is defined as selecting the
> value that would be effective had there never been any SET commands in
> the current session.
>
> To handle these cases we must keep track of many distinct values for
> each variable.  The primary values are:
>
> - actual variable contents    always the current effective value
> - reset_val           the value to use for RESET
>
> (Each GUC entry also has a boot_val which is the wired-in default
> value. This is assigned to the reset_val and the actual variable
> during InitializeGUCOptions().  The boot_val is also consulted to
> restore the correct reset_val if SIGHUP processing discovers that a
> variable formerly specified in postgresql.conf is no longer set
> there.)
>
> In addition to the primary values, there is a stack of former
> effective values that might need to be restored in future.  Stacking
> and unstacking is controlled by the GUC "nest level", which is zero
> when outside any transaction, one at top transaction level, and
> incremented for each open subtransaction or function call with a SET
> option.  A stack entry is made whenever a GUC variable is first
> modified at a given nesting level. (Note: the reset_val need not be
> stacked because it is only changed by non-transactional operations.)
>
> A stack entry has a state, a prior value of the GUC variable, a
> remembered source of that prior value, and depending on the state may
> also have a "masked" value.  The masked value is needed when SET
> followed by SET LOCAL occur at the same nest level: the SET's value is
> masked but must be remembered to restore after transaction commit.